# Date Formatting style in IOS

Tags: ios5, date-formatting

I want to get date format in style "6Mar2012 7:03:34 AM". Can anyone tell me how shall I get exact that date formatting string.I want to get it in iOS 5.0 from a NSDate Object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter with the format string `dMMMyyyy h:mm:ss a`:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dMMMyyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormat release];
```